# Is it possible to access piped variables without forkJoin or combineLatest?

Tags: typescript, rxjs, combinelatest

Is it possible to access previous pipe variables in RxJs appliances where `forkJoin()` or `combineLatest()` cannot be used, in my case due to value accumulation, without nesting pipes?

Or is a nested pipe with `switchMap()` in the following scenario even fine?

```
// this.incrementNavigation$ emits always 1
// this.decrementNavigation$ emits always -1

this.searchSuggestions$.pipe(
  // Can't use combineLatest() due to accumulation happening in scan()
  switchMap(search => {
    return merge(this.incrementNavigation$, this.decrementNavigation$).pipe( // Nesting begins...
      startWith(0),
      scan((acc: number, cur: number) => {
        if (acc+cur < 0) return search.length-1 // Need access to search variable
        if (acc+cur > search.length-1) return 0
        return acc+cur
      }),
    )
  })
).subscribe(pos => {
  this.searchNavigationPosition = pos
})
```

Comment: What's the problem with nesting `pipe()` calls?

Comment: Is it a problem. I've read numerous articles now stating this should not be done.

Comment: Are you sure you're not confusing pipes and nested subscriptions? I doubt anyone ever recommneed to not use nested pipes.

Comment: What you have looks fine. I wouldn't nest more than one or two levels with pipe (And there are almost always ways around doing so), but it's often desirable to have at least one level of nested `pipe`. This becomes most apparent when handling errors.